# How do you check if a library/ruby-gem has been loaded?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In ruby code, how would I check what external libraries are loaded? For example,

```
require 'some-library'
if is-loaded?('some-library')
  puts "this will run"
end
```

or

```
# require 'some-library' Don't load it in here
if is-loaded?('some-library')
  puts "this will not run"
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note on why I need this:
I'm working on [boom](https://github.com/holman/boom), and on windows, it will try to include 'Win32/Console/ANSI', to enable ANSI color codes like \e[36m. What I'm trying to do is if the system is windows and 'Win32/Console/ANSI' is not loaded, it would append the color codes, so the color codes are not outputted. [Here is the file.](https://github.com/holman/boom/blob/master/lib/boom/color.rb)

Comment: Why would some-library be only sometimes loaded?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Most libraries will typically define a top-level constant. The usual thing to do is to check whether that constant is defined.

```
> defined?(CSV)
#=> nil

> require "csv"
#=> true

> defined?(CSV)
#=> "constant"

> puts "loaded!" if defined?(CSV)
loaded!
#=> nil
```

Comment: Does it work for C  rb extension library example require 'rbtrace' require a C code I believe.

Answer (score 12):

`require` will throw a LoadError if it can't find the library you are trying to load.  So you can check it like this

```
begin
  require 'some-library'
  puts 'This will run.'
rescue LoadError
  puts 'This will not run'
  # error handling code here
end
```

Comment: This works at when it is required, but I need to check later on.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to safely try requiring a gem/library that may or may not be available, use something like this:

```
begin
  require 'securerandom'
rescue LoadError
  # We just won't get securerandom
end
```

This works even if the gem in question has *already* been required. In that scenario the `require` statement will do nothing and the `rescue` block will never execute.

If you are just interested in whether or not a gem/library has already been loaded, check to see if one of its constants is present. I do something like this to dynamically load additional functionality if ActiveSupport is loaded:

```
if defined?(ActiveSupport)
  require "active_support/cache/redis_store"
end
```

You can also use the opposite to load a compatibility layer if the gem/library is NOT present. For example, I use some `Hash` methods that don't exist in Ruby's core Hash implementation, but are added by ActiveSupport. So, I define those methods when my gem runs in an environment where ActiveSupport doesn't exist.

```
require 'core_ext/hash' unless defined?(ActiveSupport)
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Require Library Unless Already Loaded

For simplicity, here's how you load a library unless it's already loaded:

```
require 'RMagick' unless defined?(Magick)
```

Comment: But it is my understanding that `require` is all about loading *once*. So what's the point of this `unless` here?  Of course, it's a different matter with you expected `Magick` could have been defined independently of `RMagick`, I'm referring to your title "Require Library Unless Already Loaded".

Comment: I believe you're right. That was 6 years ago so not sure why the `unless` was necessary. Additionally, the answer really only asks for determining when a library is loaded, not loading a library, so the answer could have just been `if defined?( Magick )`.

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
def loaded?(name)
  r = Regexp.new("#{name}.rb$")
  $LOADED_FEATURES.select{|t| t.match(r) }.any?
end
```

Be sure of the name of your module (search here `$LOADED_FEATURES`).